# How to Parse Multiple JSON Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, parsing

I have data in JSON format as below:

```
[{"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"Insan Cahya Setia"},{"number":"2","label":"Name","value": "0012345"},{"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"SPV"},{"number":"4","label":"UserID","value ":"0000506"},{"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value":"0000001"},{"number":"6","label":"IP" ,"value":"50.87.4.113"},{"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"0012346"},{"number":"2","label" :"Name","value":"Insan Setia Cahya"},{"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"CS"},{"number":"4" ,"label":"UserID","value":"0000541"},{"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value":"0000002"},{"number": "6","label":"IP","value":"50.87.4.130"},{"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"0012347"},{ "number":"2","label":"Name","value":"Cahya Insan Setia"},{"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"ATM "},{"number":"4","label":"UserID","value":"0000951"},{"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value" :"-"},{"number":"6","label":"IP","value":"50.87.4.110"}]
```

I want to parse the data into a table.
I have used the query below to parse it:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"Insan Cahya Setia"},{"number":"2","label":"Name","value": "0012345"},{"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"SPV"},{"number":"4","label":"UserID","value ":"0000506"},{"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value":"0000001"},{"number":"6","label":"IP" ,"value":"50.87.4.113"},{"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"0012346"},{"number":"2","label" :"Name","value":"Insan Setia Cahya"},{"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"CS"},{"number":"4" ,"label":"UserID","value":"0000541"},{"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value":"0000002"},{"number": "6","label":"IP","value":"50.87.4.130"},{"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"0012347"},{ "number":"2","label":"Name","value":"Cahya Insan Setia"},{"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"ATM "},{"number":"4","label":"UserID","value":"0000951"},{"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value" :"-"},{"number":"6","label":"IP","value":"50.87.4.110"}]';

WITH CTE_TEMP AS (
SELECT number, label, value
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (
    number INT '$.number',
    label VARCHAR(50) '$.label',
    value VARCHAR(50) '$.value'
)
) 
, CTE_RESULT AS (
SELECT
    label,
    value,
    'Column' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY label ORDER BY number) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS columnName
FROM CTE_TEMP
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_RESULT
PIVOT
(
    MAX(value)
    FOR label IN ([PN], [Name], [Role], [UserID], [UserID CK], [IP])
) AS pivotedTable
```

And the results are as follows:

| columnName | PN | Name | Role | UserID | UserID CK | IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Column1 | 0012347 | Cahya Insan Setia | ATM | NULL | - | 50.87.4.113 |
| Column2 | 0012346 | 0012345 | CS | 0000541 | 0000002 | 50.87.4.130 |
| Column3 | Insan Cahya Setia | Insan Setia Cahya | SPV | 0000951 | 0000001 | 50.87.4.110 |

However, from the results above, the data is not neatly arranged in each row.
My hope is that the data will be like this:

| columnName | PN | Name | Role | UserID | UserID CK | IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Column1 | 0012347 | Cahya Insan Setia | ATM | 0000951 | - | 50.87.4.110 |
| Column2 | 0012346 | Insan Setia Cahya | CS | 0000541 | 0000002 | 50.87.4.130 |
| Column3 | Insan Cahya Setia | 0012345 | SPV | 0000506 | 0000001 | 50.87.4.113 |

I don't know where the logic is going wrong. And how to fix it?

- Note : The JSON data is stored in the columns of a table

Comment: The problem starts from that JSON string. Why is a key/value array used instead of objects, eg `[{'PN':'0012347','Name':'Cahya Insan Setia',...",{...}]`? The whole point of using JSON is that any object can be stored.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So how do I solve this problem?

Comment: There's no way to reconstruct the objects in that array unfortunately. The results of `FROM OPENJSON(@json)` have *no* indication of what pair belongs to what object. The `number` isn't an identifier. The only way a *human* could detect that some pairs are related is that `number` drops from `6` to `1` in the array. Relational data has no implied order though, unless `ORDER BY` is used. To keep the order `key` should be included at least

Comment: `how do I solve this problem?` don't use that JSON. Why is it used at all? Trying to reformat this takes a *lot* of effort and a lot of tricky queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But the data is formatted as above.

Comment: @siggemannen 
No. The data is just like that. I just replaced the value because it is data in my company

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254164/discussion-between-insan-cahya-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Can you explain the logic for binding the row data together a little better? For the row where IP is `50.87.4.113` why is the UserID `0000951` instead of `0000506`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning 
Sorry, correctly it should be 0000506. I misplaced that value.

Comment: There's a typo in there, `"value "` instead of `"value"`. If the JSON string is hand-written, why not create a better JSON format? *All* JSON libraries can store arrays of proper objects instead of this. JSON allows having different properties per object in an array so there's no need for label/value pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the JSON data correctly and rows make groups, a possible approach is the following statement. The idea is to make a new group when the value of the `$.value` key is equal to `1`.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[
  {"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"Insan Cahya Setia"},
  {"number":"2","label":"Name","value": "0012345"}, 
  {"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"SPV"}, 
  {"number":"4","label":"UserID","value":"0000506"}, 
  {"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value":"0000001"}, 
  {"number":"6","label":"IP" ,"value":"50.87.4.113"}, 
  {"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"0012346"}, 
  {"number":"2","label":"Name","value":"Insan Setia Cahya"}, 
  {"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"CS"},
  {"number":"4" ,"label":"UserID","value":"0000541"},
  {"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value":"0000002"},
  {"number": "6","label":"IP","value":"50.87.4.130"}, 
  {"number":"1","label":"PN","value":"0012347"},
  {"number":"2","label":"Name","value":"Cahya Insan Setia"}, 
  {"number":"3","label":"Role","value":"ATM "}, 
  {"number":"4","label":"UserID","value":"0000951"}, 
  {"number":"5","label":"UserID CK","value" :"-"}, 
  {"number":"6","label":"IP","value":"50.87.4.110"}
]';
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  
  SELECT 
    j2.[label], j2.[value],
    SUM(CASE WHEN number = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j1.[key])) AS id
  FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
    number INT '$.number',
    label VARCHAR(50) '$.label',
    value VARCHAR(50) '$.value'
  ) j2
) t
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) FOR label IN ([PN], [Name], [Role], [UserID], [UserID CK], [IP])
) p
ORDER BY id
```

Result:

| id | PN | Name | Role | UserID | UserID CK | IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Insan Cahya Setia | 0012345 | SPV | 0000506 | 0000001 | 50.87.4.113 |
| 2 | 0012346 | Insan Setia Cahya | CS | 0000541 | 0000002 | 50.87.4.130 |
| 3 | 0012347 | Cahya Insan Setia | ATM | 0000951 | - | 50.87.4.110 |

Comment: Yes, that's right, the query above has displayed what I expected. But there is another problem, why in the first row the UserID column has a NULL value? It should have the value 0000506. 
I run this query in SSMS

You can see the result in this link :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pW_zJzfV9LbKpa1ZkxgB1CJ8WrxrWfKh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Because there's no `"value"` attribute, there's a `"value "`. Do you understand just how complex this query is? For what seems like a hand-written JSON string that offers *no* benefit? First, you need *two* OPENJSON calls just to get the rows in order. Then `SUM(....)` detects *islands* of consecutive numbers and generates an Object ID. *Finally* the PIVOT call uses *known* property names to recreate the table. If you already knew the property names, why use JSON instead of a plain old table?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am most grateful for your support 

Comment: `ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j1.[key]) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is slightly faster